# Converting Repeated Record to Repeated String Array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Table A , where one of the column is a Repeated RECORD like

```
                +- children: record (repeated)
                |  |- name: string
                |  |- gender: string
                |  |- age: integer
```

I have a Table B , where one of the column is a STRING (Repeated)

```
                +- names : string (repeated)
```

Looking for options to move name list from Table A which is inside RECORD to a String Array of Table B .

Any suggestions will be of great help

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ARRAY` function. Try this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(children))
  ) AS names
FROM `dataset.table`
```

It creates new arrays from just the `name` field within the structs, then converts the arrays to strings.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

If you expect to get array you can use below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(children)) AS names
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

you can test / play with it using dummy data as

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>('abc1','m',12),('xyz1','m',13),('uvw1','f',14)] children UNION ALL
  SELECT [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>('abc2','f',12),('xyz2','m',13),('uvw2','f',14)] 
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(children)) AS names
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

output is

```sql
Row names    
1   abc1     
    xyz1     
    uvw1     
2   abc2     
    xyz2     
    uvw2
```

In case if you would expected string

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(name) FROM UNNEST(children)) AS names
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

You can test / play with it using same dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>('abc1','m',12),('xyz1','m',13),('uvw1','f',14)] children UNION ALL
  SELECT [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>('abc2','f',12),('xyz2','m',13),('uvw2','f',14)] 
)
SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(name) FROM UNNEST(children)) AS names
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

and output now is

```sql
Row names    
1   abc1,xyz1,uvw1   
2   abc2,xyz2,uvw2
```